# How can I sort an array of Bus objects by their bus number (buses.number)?

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

Lets say I have the following array of Bus objects:

```
var buses = [Bus]()
```

After the buses array fills up I would like to sort the array of buses by bus number (which is a String for example "501"). Each Bus object has a bus number (buses[index].number). There are no duplicate bus numbers. How can I I do this sort? I see filter around but i'm not really sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so simple by [sort method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) in swift,

```
let sortedBuses = buses.sort({ $0.number > $1.number })
```

or

```
buses.sortInPlace({ $0.number > $1.number }) // this sorts arrays and saves it in self.
```

Comment: That is awesome thank you. I will accept the answer when I can in 7 minutes.

Comment: Keep in mind that if `number` is a `String` then this will do an alphabetic sort, not a numeric sort. In other words, bus 200 will come before bus 8, for example.

Comment: Should I use sortInPlace instead of sort? Xcode is giving me a warning.

Comment: Sort using closure, but take care of the swift version.

Swift 2.3 -> `sort` returns a sorted array, but `sortInPlace` sorts the same array

Swift 3.0 -> `sorted` returns a sorted array, but `sort` sorts the same array